# cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' при работе с Django 4.0.1

Tags: python, django

При запуске сервера получаю следующую ошибку (работаю на django 4.0.1)

> "File "C:\Users\root\PycharmProjects\djangoAPItest\DjangoAPI\DjangoAPI\urls.py", line 19, in 
> from django.conf.urls import url,include
> ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls'
> (C:\Users\root\PycharmProjects\djangoAPItest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls_*init*_.py)"

мой urls.py содержит следующий код:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from EmployeeApp import views

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^department$', views.departmentApi),
    url(r'^department/([0-9]+)$', views.departmentApi)
]
```

При откате django до версии 3.2.4 на которой пишет автор все работает корректно.

Понимаю, что ошибка в отсутствии импортируемого имени в файле *init*.py фреймворка django 4.0.1, но не понимаю как исправить данную ситуацию. Работать дальше на старой версии django не хочется, не зря ведь его апгрейдят :)

Подскажите, как правильно написать код, чтобы уйти от данной ошибки?

Comment: В доках для версии 4 показаны примеры с path и re_path вместо url: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/ Т.к. у вас в формате регулярных выражений пути указаны, то проще использовать re_path.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо больше, все заработало :)

Comment: Ваш код написан аж для Django версии 1.x, поэтому вам стоит почитать актуальную документацию (о грядущем удалении django.conf.urls было объявлено ещё полтора года назад (версия 3.1), а тонкие намёки на грядущее удаление появились ещё четыре года назад (версия 2.0), наверное стоило следить за новостями)

Comment: @andreymal, это мой первый проект на django и я пишу по существующим статьям и видео. К сожалению с устаревшими данными. Четыре года назад я не знал, что такое python :)

Comment: @andreymal, Вы как профессионал своего дела можете записать видео уроки на django4.0 с подробным разбором предстоящих нововведений. Уверен молодому поколению программистов это даст большой рывок в вперед.